# How do I represent this using JPA?

Tags: jpa

I would like a 'RolesPlayed' entity with the following columns

- user
- role
- department/project/group

All the three columns above constitute a composite primary key. I would like to know if defining a column to be one of department/project/group possible ? If yes, how ? Or do I need to break the entity into DepartmentRoles, GroupRoles and ProjectRoles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use polymorphism with an abstract base class to do that.

```
@Entity
public class RolePlayed {

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    private Body body;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Body {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Department extends Body {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Project extends Body {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Group extends Body {
    ...
}
```

Check out the [Polymorphism section in the Java Enterprise tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqn) for a good overview.

Alternatively, you could also make the `RolePlayed` entity abstract, with `DepartmentRole`, `GroupRole` and `ProjectRole` implementations.